# SQL deduplication within groupby

Tags: sql, duplicates

In this sql table

[image]

I would like to group on fields A and B.

```
SELECT A, B, count(*) from table
GROUP BY A,B
```

However, my table has duplicates with different vintages.

How would I modify this query to select only the most recent Data Vintage within each group object  and end up with

[image]

Comment: Solutions could vary depending on RDBMS (not tagged) but does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Comment: Looks like @Ariel' s answer will work. Thanks!